# Proceso de conexion a base de datos en servidor tardia - Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, validación, conexión

me ha surgido un problema el cual hasta ahora no he podido saber como solucionarlo puesto que en mi aplicacion al ejecutarla y entrar al form donde tengo un datagridview tarda en empezar con las validaciones y manejo de errores cuando no se establece la conexion a la base de datos, estuve haciendo pruebas apagando el wifi para validar que mi programa no colapse o se ponga el mensaje de "No responde" ya que sin las validaciones pasa eso y se detiene la aplicacion, pero con las validaciones que agregue, al entrar a este form donde principalmente ejecuta mi funcion para mostrar los registros en mi datagridview he detectado que tarda en abrir el form y luego empieza las validaciones de la conexion al servidor de mi base de datos, para despues pasar con las validaciones para ejecutar mi consulta a esta misma y guardar mis registros en una lista.

Me gustaria que me apoyasen a corregirme si estoy haciendo algo mal y por eso tarda en entrar al form, les dejo mis funciones con la conexion y la consulta, ademas de la funcion para mostrar los resultados a mi dgv.

Conexion:

```
public ConnectionDB()
        {
            int maxRetries = 3; // Número máximo de intentos de conexión
            int retryCount = 0; // Contador de intentos de conexión

            while (retryCount < maxRetries)
            {
                try
                {
                    connection = new SqlConnection("User ID = user; Password=1234;Initial Catalog = p_TRDatabase; Server=Server;");
                    connection.Open();
                    // Realizar operaciones con la base de datos

                    // Si la conexión es exitosa, salir del bucle
                    break;
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    // Manejar el error de conexión
                    MessageBox.Show("Error de conexión a la base de datos: " + ex.Message);
                    // Tomar las acciones necesarias para manejar el error

                    // Incrementar el contador de intentos de conexión
                    retryCount++;
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
                    if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Verificar si se alcanzó el número máximo de intentos sin éxito
            if (retryCount == maxRetries)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo establecer la conexión después de " + maxRetries + " intentos.");
                // Tomar las acciones necesarias en caso de que no se pueda establecer la conexión
            }
        }
```

Consulta:

```
public List<IncapacitiesDto> VerRegistrosIncapacities(string condicion)
        {
            try
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "VerRegistrosIncapacidades";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condicion", condicion);

                connection.Open();

                LeerFilas = command.ExecuteReader();
                List<IncapacitiesDto> incapacidadesDtos = new List<IncapacitiesDto>();
                while (LeerFilas.Read())
                {
                    incapacidadesDtos.Add(new IncapacitiesDto()
                    {
                        WorkdayID = LeerFilas.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : LeerFilas.GetInt32(0),
                        EmployeeName = LeerFilas.IsDBNull(1) ? string.Empty : LeerFilas.GetString(1),
                        JobPosition = LeerFilas.IsDBNull(2) ? string.Empty : LeerFilas.GetString(2),
                        Manager = LeerFilas.IsDBNull(3) ? string.Empty : LeerFilas.GetString(3),
                        Director = LeerFilas.IsDBNull(4) ? string.Empty : LeerFilas.GetString(4),
                        Comment = LeerFilas.IsDBNull(5) ? string.Empty : LeerFilas.GetString(5),
                    });
                }
                LeerFilas.Close();
                connection.Close();
                return incapacidadesDtos;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Manejo de errores aquí
                MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error en la consulta");
                
                return new List<IncapacitiesDto>(); // O cualquier otro manejo de errores adecuado
            }

        }
```

Funcion:

```
private void VerRegistrosIncapacidades(string condicion)
        {           
            IncapacitiesDao dao = new IncapacitiesDao();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dao.VerRegistrosIncapacities(condicion);                                    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

debes especificar la instancia del SQL Server, también verifica que use el puerto estándar, sino especifica el puerto del servidor.

Aquí está un ejemplo de una cadena de conexión:

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Sino funciona por nombre puedes usar la ip.

En este enlace hay varios ejemplos de cadenas de conexión para diferentes casos:

[ConnectionStrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/)

Comment: Me parece que esto no tiene nada que ver ocn lo que pregunto.. en que punto dijo que no sabe hacer la conexion a la db?

Comment: Creo que el problema se debe a que no encuentra la instancia del servidor, por eso tarda en iniciar el form, por eso sugerí cambiar la cadena de conexion especificando el nombre de la instancia o usuando ip.

Comment: Yo te creo.. pero si fuera asi, entonces su codigo no cargaria lo siguiente, y dice que si carga... la forma de la cadena de conexion, no va a darle mas o menos velocidad a la conexion....